# Dynamically create categories for SQLite pivot/crosstab

Tags: sqlite, pivot, crosstab

I realise it is possible to create a crosstab within sqlite, but is it possible to dynamically determine the relevant categories/columns at runtime rather than hardcoding them?

Given the following example, it can get rather tedious ...

```
SELECT 
shop_id,
sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Fiesta' THEN units END) as Fiesta,
sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Focus' THEN units END) as Focus,
sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Puma' THEN units END) as Puma,
sum(units) AS total

FROM sales
GROUP BY shop_id
```

I managed to do this in SQLServer in a [stored proceedure](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx) before and wondered if there was anything equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that in SQLite, since analytic means in SQLite lack [many usefull features](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSqlAnalyticalFunctions) available in heavier RDBMSes. [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/tktview?tn=1424) is the corresponding ticket, but it is in the pending status.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. 
So weird that something like MS Access has it, yet it's so tricky to actually get the equivalent in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but anyway: I faked something like this in Ruby on Rails. For my purposes it works well.

```ruby
  def self.yearstats(attr)
    # Determine number of columns 
    minyear = self.select("strftime('%Y', min(recorded_at)) AS minyear").first.minyear.to_i
    maxyear = self.select("strftime('%Y', max(recorded_at)) AS maxyear").first.maxyear.to_i
    # Stitch SQL query. Use explicit same column name to not confuse Rails' typecasting.
    select_str = ["strftime('#{minyear}/%m/%d %H:%m', recorded_at) AS recorded_at"]
    (minyear..maxyear).to_a.each do |y|
      # avg because the table might have multiple rows per day
      select_str += ["avg(case when strftime('%Y', recorded_at)='#{y}' then #{attr} end) AS value#{y}"]
    end
    self.select(select_str.join(",")).group("strftime('%m/%d', recorded_at)").all.collect {|row|
      [row.recorded_at.utc.to_i*1000] + (minyear..maxyear).to_a.collect { |y| row.send("value#{y}") }
    }
  end
```

Note that for the first column I used a (fake) date using a fixed first year so that my graphing routines get a "real" date, not just day/month display. This is a little dirty but it works for my purposes. (Improvements still welcome...)

Instead of getting `minyear` and `maxyear`, you might want to do a SELECT DISTINCT.. to get the unique list of categories and modify the code appropriately.