# How to do calculations with crosstab/pivot via case in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot

To do a crosstab/pivot in sqlite one can use the `case` statement as described, eg, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921070/dynamically-create-categories-for-sqlite-pivot-crosstab). However, one cannot do calculations on such 'generated' columns, ie, divide the content of the 'Puma' column by the 'Fiesta' column.

My workaround has been to create an auxiliary `view` containing the 'Puma' and 'Fiesta' columns and `join` this `view` to the main 'crosstab' output and divide the columns from the joined auxiliary table.

```
CREATE VIEW aux_table AS SELECT
    shop_id,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Fiesta' THEN units END) as Fiesta,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Focus' THEN units END) as Focus`
FROM sales
GROUP BY shop_id;

SELECT 
    shop_id,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Fiesta' THEN units END) as Fiesta,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Focus' THEN units END) as Focus,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Puma' THEN units END) as Puma,
    at.Fiesta/at.Focus 'ratio between Fiesta and Focus'
FROM sales
JOIN aux_table at ON
     sales.shop_id = at.shop_id
GROUP BY shop_id;
```

But I wonder whether there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just do the sums again, like so:

```
SELECT 
    shop_id,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Fiesta' THEN units END) as Fiesta,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Focus' THEN units END) as Focus,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Puma' THEN units END) as Puma,
    sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Fiesta' THEN units END) / sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Focus' THEN units END) as Ratio
FROM sales
GROUP BY shop_id
```

Or, faster, you can wrap it up in a subquery, like this:

```
select
    shop_id,
    Fiesta,
    Focus,
    Puma,
    Fiesta/Focus as Ratio
from
    (
    SELECT 
        shop_id,
        sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Fiesta' THEN units END) as Fiesta,
        sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Focus' THEN units END) as Focus,
        sum(CASE WHEN product = 'Puma' THEN units END) as Puma
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY shop_id
    ) x
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I had only tried: `(CASE WHEN ...)/(CASE WHEN ...)`  and not `avg((CASE WHEN ...)/avg(CASE WHEN ...)`, as in my case I did not need `avg`, `sum` or the like.